# Какой control использовать для вывода таблицы кроме DataGridView и ListView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, элементы-управления, .net-4.8

Есть данные, которые нужно отобразить и взаимодействовать так-же, как в брандмауэре Windows в правилах для входящий и исходящих подключений (список-таблица).
[image]
Т.е. требуется отображение иконок, текста, колонок, ПКМ-клик с меню, выделение строки, сортировка.
DataGridView для таких целей слишком перегружен и неповоротлив, очень много надо отрезать и переназначать.
Попробовал ListView - уже значительно получше, не перегружен, но сильно ограничен, выделяется только текст из первой колонки, и только при попадании именно по тексту, а не по всей ширине колонки.
[image]
Доработать ListView куда проще (предположительно), но может уже есть подходящий Winform Control...

Comment: Это обычный listview.

Comment: Более подходящего нет.

Comment: Есть тогда где-нибудь примеры как можно его "прокачать" чтобы выделение было во всю ширину и отображение иконки?

Comment: [ListView.FullRowSelect](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.fullrowselect?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: DataGridView вполне реализует то, что вы перечислили. Включить ему двойную буферизацию для быстрой отрисовки. Насчёт неповоротливости: выделение большого набора данных действительно медленно. Но всё остальное быстро.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov когда в реалтайме из другого потока в DataGridView приходит обнова по какой-то колонке в 3000+ строк - начинается лагодром, ускорять - ускоряли, но фризы и 5% нагрузка на проц всё равно остаются, если добавлять данные в реалтайме - то всё ещё хуже. Поэтому DataGridView только в крайнем случае, например когда нужно редактирование. Вообще нужен таблице-подобный журнал. Чтобы в журнал добавляли экземпляры классов и они отображались в таблице, а при клике на строку был вызов метода класса (например открытие другого окна с подробностями), ListBox подходит идеально, но нет колонок.

Comment: @aepot спасибо так намного лучше.

Comment: @aepot Если в нём ещё можно сделать изменение размера шрифта, фоновую заливку, иконки, и сортировку - вообще будет идеально.

Comment: Вы серьезно в дизайнере не видите свойств этого контрола?

Comment: @aepot не вижу как крепить иконку.

Comment: Это творческая задача. можете завести отдельную колонку под картинки.

Comment: Не грузите сразу много строк (данных) в любой контрол. Подгружайте их по мере необходимости (при прокрутке). Используйте [виртуальный режим](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/implementing-virtual-mode-wf-datagridview-control?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)